# Display Images with More Fields yes / no

Tags: customization

I am creating a site and installed the More Fields plugin option to create custom fields in the posts.

I'll have an area for downloads, which will provide Word and Excel files to download.

If I create a field of type yes / no, as I call the code so that "If you marked YES" shows the image, and if you have marked as NO, hides the image.

Can anyone help me?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a new "more field" radio button. For its value use `*Show, Hide`. The asterisk defaults to  "Show".

**PHP**

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_image', true);

if ( $value == 'Show' ) {
    echo '<img src="myimage.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: That's right, it worked correctly.
Only two details, I had to create a checkbox, radio button using it will not let me use values​​.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @user15269 Then please mark this as solution. This is the check mark on the left below the voting arrows.